# Can't sign in to UCWA

Tags: azure-active-directory, skype-for-business, ucwa

I have Skype for Business application set up and ready to use. I can sign in with Administrator user and I already gave Admin Consent to the app.

But, with other users(not Admin) I can't sign in. What may be the problem here?

The response I get is:
[image]

Comment: The X-Ms-diagnostics header says "User is not SIP enabled.". Did you double-check, that the user you are trying to sign in as is actually enabled for SfB?

Comment: @RasmusW the user is in the Azure directory. How do I check if it's SfB enabled or not?

Comment: Check whether he has a license (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Assign-licenses-to-users-in-Office-365-for-business-997596b5-4173-4627-b915-36abac6786dc), and I would probably also do a test-login using the SfB client.

Comment: @RasmusW opps! I didn't even know that I had to assign licenses.... Thanks I'll assign a lisence to the user and try again.

Comment: You definitely need a SfB seat associated with the user otherwise they cannot receive communications (message, A/V).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was (a bit silly I must admit) I didn't have any SfB subscription for the other users. That was why I  couldn't sign in except with admin user.

After we purchased more subscriptions, there were no problem.